# Four level tree view for categories in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, treeview, spree

I want to implement a four level tree view like in left sidebar of this[flash web page](http://www.sodamco.com/product.php).I want to implement it in spree and make subcategories of products.I have tried sidebar used in spree guides ,but it lists all values after second level.How can i implement this? Suggest me right javascript / rails practises that get my work done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spree backend has got taxonomies, as given in the documentation, you can check the code

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/configuring_taxonomies.html